# About existence of derivative

Tags: calculus

Please give me details that either derivative exist or not at end points of any interval? Thanks to everybody who will help me.

Comment: in end points you can define the laterals derivades because you don't know how the function is in the other side of the end point

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing calculus of one real variable, the derivative exists if and only if the limit quotient in the definition exists. If need be, you can check it independently from each direction, but this is usually not necessary. On end points, you can use one-sided derivatives.